# How to instantiate a .NET FirefoxDriver when FF is installed in non-default location?

Tags: selenium, selenium2, webdriver, c#

My Firefox 5 is installed not at the default location. So, I tried with the following to create a `FirefoxDriver`:

```
private IWebDriver driver;

[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
    var ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(@"D:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox 4\firefox.exe");
    var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\2z4r45zq.default");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, firefoxProfile);
}
```

But the `FirefoxBinary` instantiation throws an exception, stating that:
"*The system cannot find the file specified*". But my firefox.exe is there. Also, I added it to my `PATH`. I saw some suggestion to use *webdriver.firefox.bin* in java environment. Is there any equivalent in .NET environment?

BTW, I am using Win 7(64), Firefox 5, Selenium 2 .NET webdriver. Thanks

Comment: which file it cannot find binary or profile?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{

 FirefoxProfile SeleniumProf = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\location of your custom profile");
 driver = new FirefoxDriver(SeleniumProf);
}
```

You don't need to declare the binary. It works for me and I'm using FireFox 9 on Windows 7